# Where I can find more example on Jgrid using struts2

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts2

I want practice on all types of sub grid examples, please suggest me any website, tutorial or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the site hosting the demo application using Struts2 with Jquery plugin

[struts2-jquery-grid-showcase](http://www.weinfreund.de/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/index.action)

Additionally you can download the source code from [struts2-jquery Download](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/downloads/list)

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi URL is not working right now. can u suggest any other.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this site. You can see many examples
http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html